# AngularJS display element if it's in the array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs, checkbox

I am trying to repopulate a group of checkboxes based on user permissions that have previously been selected.

I created an array of the permission id's and want to compare the input element to the array of id's and display the checkbox as checked if they there is a match, otherwise display an unchecked checkbox.

This is how I created the `$scope.assigned` array:

```
$scope.user.$promise.then(function(result) {
    $scope.user = result;
    $scope.assigned = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.user.permissions, function(value, key) {
        this.push(value.id);
    }, $scope.assigned);

console.log($scope.assigned);
```

When the `$scope.assigned` is logged to the console, I am left with an array such as `["2", "3", "4"]` representing the previously selected permission ids. Now I want to compare those to the `permissions.id`

the view:

```
<h4>Manage Permissions</h4>
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="permission in permissions">
    <label>
        <input ng-if="permission.id == assigned" type="checkbox" ng-checked="true" checklist-model="user.permissions" checklist-value="permission.id" class="checkbox-inline">
        {{ permission.display_name }}
    </label>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
```

I thought that I could do something like `ng-if="permission.id == assigned"` but that does not work. I need a way to check if permission.id matches anything inside of assigned.

I previously did this in PHP like this: `if(in_array($permission['id'], $assigned))`

How can I accomplish this in AngularJS? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `indexOf`:

```
ng-if="assigned.indexOf(permission.id) != -1"
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks @merlin! Didn't know about indexOf(), I'm still very new to JavaScript and AngularJS. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @MitchGlenn Also take a look at the [compatibility table of `Array.prototype.indexOf`](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/) if you want to support old browsers.